# How to get list of installed printers at remote machine

Tags: java, printers

I know how to get the installed printer on the local machine below is the code:

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
    System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName()); 
}
```

but could not find the way to look for all available printers to the specific location or in the LAN.

I am implementing the application where validation is required when user pass the printer location. Because of that I want to check whether user has entered valid existing printer to that location.

Comment: What is `PrintServiceLookup`?

Comment: @LutzHorn  its a class which helps to lookup printer at the local machine

Comment: [PrintServiceLookup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html)